# JAXB: Can I make XmlAttribute's parameter "required=true" to default?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have

```
@XmlAttribute(required=true)
```

in hundreds places in a projects.

**Can I make this default?**...

...So that I then only need to specify

```
@XmlAttribute(required=false)
```

when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that behaviour is hard-wired. However, the `required` attribute is really a lightweight alternative to a proper XML schema. If you need better control over document validation, then I suggest you define an XML Schema for your documents, and inject the schema into the `JAXBContext`. The documents will then be checked on marshalling and unmarshalling, and you won't have to rely on the annotations for validation.

Comment: Would you suggest that I first let JAXB generate a schema file, then modify it, and then let JAXB use that for validation?